# How to keep ratio when change plot size in R markdown Knitr HTML output to make everything visible?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

My system is win 10,with R 3.5.3 and Rstudio 1.1.463

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(CMC)
library(mirt)
alpha.curve(LSAT6)
```
````

Run above R `markdown` script and `Knitr` to html,you will see a plot as below:
[image]

There's apart of plot(`item_4`) cannot be seen at the top left side.That's a problem.
Then I revised  plot chunk to `{r,fig.height=8}`, I will a get output as below:
[image]

There's no invisible  part but the plot ratio totally changed.

How to keep  ratio when change plot size in R markdown Knitr HTML output?

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem. When I knit your code, everything works fine and nothing is cut off. Nevertheless, you can use the option `fig.asp`, see here: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots

Comment: @J_F,add my system version information. Did you see `item4`?